# 2 different references from the same object to two different objects from the same class - DJANGO database

Tags: python, django, django-models, relationship

I want to have a match object with two team references.
I.E(old json database example):
I would like to easeliy be able to access each team and possibly swap side. That's why I want to use Django example 2, as then I can reference each team from the Match Object. But example gives an error about each reference duplicating each other...

```json
{
  "dateTime": "",
  "matchID":"0fb86bcf-c700-4429-b5a9-558ca9b95a03",
  "team1ID":"e372b7f4-008f-4503-beee-1d6756361fea",
  "team2ID":"802b4705-d812-4a88-9246-b14bd18938d8",
  "format":3,
  "division":"Relegation",
  "league":leagueRef,
  "game":leagueRef,
}
```

Django example 1:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    ...
    team = models.ManyToManyField(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
```

Django example 2:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    ...
    team1 = models.OneToOneField(
         Team,
         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
         )
    team2 = models.OneToOneField(
         Team,
         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

When one uses a `OneToOneField` (or any other related field) Django automatically makes a reverse accessor on the other side of the relation. So in the model team Django will automatically make an attribute with the name `match` to access this related object. The problem is you have two of these fields making Django not know what name to use for them.

You can solve this by specifying a [`related_name` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
class Match(models.Model):
    ...
    team1 = models.OneToOneField(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='match_1'
    )
    team2 = models.OneToOneField(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='match_2'
    )
```

> **Note**: By using a `OneToOneField` it means that one team can only have one entry in the `Match` table (once from both sides). So in
> essence with this a team can only be in 2 matches. Perhaps you want to
> use a [`ForeignKey` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) instead.